# application of rectification theorem on first integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Be $X:\Delta\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a vector field of class $C^{1}$ where $\Delta\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open. We say that $f:\Delta\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a first integral of $X$ in $\Delta$ if

(a) $f$ isn't constant in any open subset of $\Delta$

(b)$f$ is constant in every orbit of $X$

I want to prove this affirmation:

If $X$ has a first integral $f$ such that $Df(p)\neq 0$, then there is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $X|_{V}$ is $C^1$-conjugate to a vector field as $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,...,,Y_{n-1},0)$.

I think that I should use the rectification theorem. I have prove that if $X$ has a first integral $f$ such that $Df(p)\neq 0$ then $Df(p).X(p)=0$. But this doens't lead me to the fact that I have a regular point on $X$, so I can't find out how to use the idea of the rectification theorem.